Error when running colcon build --packages-select my_py_pkg --symlink-install
when I run colcon build --packages-select my_py_pkg --symlink-install
I get the following error:
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~/ros2_ws$ colcon build --packages-select my_py_pkg --symlink-install 
Starting >>> my_py_pkg
--- stderr: my_py_pkg                   
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py:40: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  easy_install.initialize_options(self)
---
Finished <<< my_py_pkg [0.77s]

Summary: 1 package finished [0.85s]
  1 package had stderr output: my_py_pkg
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~/ros2_ws$ 

Any idea on how to fix this?
I know its a warning, but how do you fix it?
